# python pandas groupby sorting and concatenating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a panda data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 'b': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b'], 'c': ['o','o','o','o','p','p','p'], 'd': [ [2,3,4], [1,3,3,4], [3,3,1,2], [4,1,2], [8,2,1], [0,9,1,2,3], [4,3,1] ], 'e': [13,12,5,10,3,2,5] })
```

What I want is:

First group by columns a, b, c --- there are two groups

Then sort within each group according to column e in an ascending order

Lastly concatenate within each group column d

So the result I want is:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2], 'b':['a','b'], 'c':['o','p'], 'd':[[3,3,1,2,4,1,2,1,3,3,4,2,3,4],[0,9,1,2,3,8,2,1,4,3,1]]})
```

Could anyone share some quick/elegant ways to get around this? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sort by column `e`, group by `a`, `b` and `c` and then use a list comprehension to concatenate the `d` column (flatten it). Notice that we can use `sort` and then `groupby` since groupby will

> preserve the order in which observations are sorted within each group:

according to the [doc here:](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html)

```
(df.sort_values('e').groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['d']
                    .apply(lambda g: [j for i in g for j in i]).reset_index())
```

[image]

An alternative to list-comprehension is the chain from itertools:

```
from itertools import chain
(df.sort_values('e').groupby(['a', 'b', 'c'])['d']
                    .apply(lambda g: list(chain.from_iterable(g))).reset_index())
```